@EnableScheduling annotation is not woking in Kotlin project
I have a Kotlin poroject, created using spring-boot 2.6.4 and java 11. Here is my main class:
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
open class MailApplication {

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(vararg args: String) {
            runApplication<EcoMailApplication>(*args)
        }
    }
}

I also have another class to start my application with additional configs:
object LocalRunner {

    @JvmStatic
    fun main(vararg args: String) {
        System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "stubMode,DEV,LOCAL")
        System.setProperty("logback.configurationFile", "logger/logback.xml")
        System.setProperty("logging.config", "classpath:logger/logback.xml")
        MailApplication.main(*args)
    }
}

So, when I run my application using "MailApplication.main" function, my scheduled services work without any problems.
But when I run application using "LocalRunner.main" class, no any methods, annotated with @Scheduled annotation start. Why is that? How can I enable scheduled jobs, when running in local profile?
edit. project structure:
└── com
    └── acme
        ├── LocalRunner.kt
        ├── MailApplication.kt


What happens if you start from MailApplication, but set those same system properties another way (using -D flags on the command line)?  (That should distinguish whether the failure is due to the properties, or to LocalRunner itself somehow.)

Thank you very much. Now I can fix the error.
I started app with parameters and got the same bug. Then I removed the "-Dlogging.config" param and the error disappeared. So it looks like I have problems with logger configuration, that affects scheduling. Will fix this and post solution.

Silly error.
My LocalRunner includes this line of code:
System.setProperty("logging.config", "classpath:logger/logback.xml")

and that "logback.xml" file sets logging level as "ERROR". Therefore I don't see any log.info("..") messages from my scheduled task.
Application itself works fine. I just did not see any messages. ))

Very likely a package problem.
Please update your Question to let us know the packages that the two classes are defined.
Spring looks for annotations in your class structure only DOWN from the point you start the application.  So if you had a structure like this:
└── com
    └── acme
        ├── MailApplication.kt
        ├── local
        │   └── LocalRunner.kt
        ├── model
        │   └── MyModel.kt
        └── service
            └── MyService.kt

... then starting from MailApplication.kt all other Spring annotated classes of yours are in that package com.acme or below.
But if you start from com.acme.local.LocalRunner then the Spring annotated classes you want to be found won't be found because they are higher up in the class hierarchy.
You can override this default behaviour in many ways, but start simply by moving the LocalRunner into the same package as MailApplication

Noup. MailApplication & LocalRunner are in the same package (root of the project).
Anyway thanks for suggestion.
